Pulumi/Terraform refresh of aws elasticache:ReplicationGroup takes 30s each time
I've created AWS Elasticache Redis cluster of one node using Replication group object as described here https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/aws/api-docs/elasticache/replicationgroup/ . Below is my code that creates one primary node in cluster mode disabled.
Each time I run pulumi refresh it's stuck for exactly 30 seconds refreshing aws:elasticache:ReplicationGroup, that looks like timeout or something like that, but not as expected behavior.
Please help me understand if this is a wrong configuration, pulumi/terraform bug etc.
self.redis_replication_group = aws.elasticache.ReplicationGroup(
            f"redis-replgr-{vars.env_name}-{vars.stack_name}",
            at_rest_encryption_enabled=True,
            description="redis replication group",
            engine_version="7.1",
            ip_discovery="ipv4",
            maintenance_window="sat:00:00-sat:01:00",
            network_type="ipv4",
            node_type="cache.t4g.micro",
            num_cache_clusters=1,
            apply_immediately=True,
            multi_az_enabled=False,
            parameter_group_name="default.redis7",
            port=vars.chat_cache_server_port,
            replication_group_id=f"chat-cache-{vars.env_name}-{vars.stack_name}",
            security_group_ids=[ cache_sg.id ],
            snapshot_retention_limit=1,
            snapshot_window="23:00-00:00",
            subnet_group_name=self.redis_subnet_group.name,
            auto_minor_version_upgrade=False,
            notification_topic_arn=None,
            tags={
                **vars.common_tags,
            },
            opts=pulumi.ResourceOptions(parent=self)
        )

I haven't found any issues on this topic. Switching apply_immediately=False had no effect.
